# Import Document from SQL to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, data

Is there any out of the box way by which I can import the documents from Sql database to SharePoint 2010 document libraries ?

I googled for this but I got only programmatic approaches which states to create a bunch of code to get the task done.

Isn't there any tool (open source) or PowerShell script through which I can get the documents to my document library from Sql database(stored as BLOB). ?

Answer (score 0):

Importing them into SP will most likely need to be done programmatically. I can't think of any third party (open source) tools that would do this. Perhaps someone else knows of one.

If you just need access to those documents via a list, you could always create an external list with BCS. The data won't live in SP. Note that workflows can't be applied to external lists.

Comment: the external list you are talking about will be LISTS and I want them as libraries. 

how can I achieve this goal with that approach.?

the file will be stored as Binary.

will that cause any error ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use sharepoint designer and can add external content type .

Here the link which i followed , you too can have a look : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/sharepoint/794/sharepoint-2010-connect-sql-server-external-content-type

Comment: thanks for the help, but I guess this approach won't work as the external list might not support for the binaries stored in the DB for the documents. 

and I want a Document Library to be created